# Why can't I retrieve data from my Json file?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I'm trying to get data from my json file for a small test project. I'm not getting any error in the developer tools and when I do console.log(data) after the request I get data from the file.

This is my angular code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope,     $http){
  $scope.todos = [];
  $http.get('db/todos.json')
    .then(function(data){
      $scope.todos = data;

    });
 }]);
```

This is my html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<base href="/">
<title>My todo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container" ng-controller="MainController">
     <div class="row">
     <h1>Your todos</h1>
     <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
        {{ todo.name }}
      <li>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In my site the ng-repeat just prints out six bullet points which is wrong because I've got only two entries in my json file. Also this is what I get from my console.log(data):

```
Object {data: Object, status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}
config: Object
data:Object
headers:(name)
status:200
statusText:"OK"
__proto__:Object
```

Any ideas of what I've probably missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `.then` the actual response data is in `response.data`, so your code works if you change it like this:

```
.then(function(response){
    $scope.todos = response.data;
});
```

Comment: hmm, didn't know that, I was working with .success for most of the time. Now I'm getting the `<li>` elements printed twice but there is no data. Is there also a different way to access the data on the index.html file?

Comment: @captain Nope, that's still the same, could you do `console.log(response.data)` in the `.then` and check if it's all good ?

Comment: This comes out in the console: `Object {todos: Array[2]}` with a dropdown menu where `0: Object checked: "false" name: "Go shopping"` and then the next object which is almost the same

Comment: `$scope.todos = response.data` should be `$scope.todos = response.data.todos;` then

Comment: This works, but now I'm getting a third bullet point from the `<li>` element. I have to figure it out.

Comment: @captain If you put your code in a jsfiddle/plunkr with some mockup data I'll have a look